# Cannot handle exceptions thrown in a task and continue where it left off

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I have defined an extension method to capture exceptions thrown in a task and write it to log.

```
public static Task IgnoreExceptions(this Task task)
    {
        task.ContinueWith(t =>  
            {
                var ignored = t.Exception;
                Console.WriteLine("Error" + ignored.Message);
            },
            CancellationToken.None,
            TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously | TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);

        return task;
    }
```

However, it doesn't seem to work for me. The execution does not continue where it should be. Can anyone tell what's wrong with my IgnoreExceptions?

```
try { 
    await DoSomething().IgnoreExceptions().ConfigureAwait(false);

    await DoSomethingElse().IgnoreExceptions().ConfigureAwait(false);
}
catch(Exception e){
   // If DoSomething() throws, the error is written to console but the code reaches here instead of continuing to call DoSomethingElse()
}
```

Comment: `DoSomething` wouldn't be a `void` return type by chance?

Answer (score 0):

The problem of your implementation is that you're returning the original task. Return the one that is created by `ContinueWith` might work (I haven't tested it).

old:

```
task.ContinueWith(...);
return task;
```

new:

```
var result = task.ContinueWith(...);
return result;
```

But I would prefer an `async/await` approach and rewrite the extension method like that:

```
public static async Task IgnoreException(this Task task)
{
    try
    {
        await task;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Error: {ex.Message}");
    }
}
```

[DEMO](https://dotnetfiddle.net/lJSaN2)